# CodeMirror issue: Error parsing forward channel Error: Invalid maps at transformData

Tags: javascript, meteor, codemirror, ui-codemirror

Trying to get simple version of codemirror up and running but when I go to a document on two diff browsers (or one in incog), I get this error in the console:

Error parsing forward channel Error: Invalid maps at transformData

These are two diff users logged in and accessing the same doc. Worked fine when no one was logged in and it was just two diff browsers accessing doc. I set up the settings.json file as instructed in the root and I am running meteor 1.2.1 as that's the version that still works with Sharejs. I'm running it with: meteor --release 1.2.1 --settings settings.json.

```
{
 "sharejs": {
 "options": {
      "accounts_auth": {
        "authorize": {
            "collection": "documents",
            "token_validations": {
              "or": {
                "invitedUsers": "is_in_array",
                "userId": "is_equal"
              }
            },
            "apply_on": [
              "read",
              "update",
              "create",
              "delete"
            ]
        },
        "authenticate": {
            "collection": "users",
            "token_validations": {
              "_id": "is_equal"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the HTML when the docs render both have the correct docid (ie the same docid)... but obviously I don't see the text mirroring.

Using simple codemirror version (`{{> sharejsCM docid=docid id="editor"}}`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example in https://www.coursera.org/learn/web-application-development/lecture/QAxTR/textcircle
Code is: textcircle.html:

```
<head>
    <title>Text Circle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Text Circle - a Collaboration Tool.</h1>
    {{> editor}}
</body>
<template name="editor">
   {{> sharejsCM docid=docId id="Editor"}} 
</template>
```

----  textcircle.js:

```
this.Documents = new Mongo.Collection("documents");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.editor.helpers( {
    docId: function () {
      var doc = Documents.findOne();
      if (doc) {
        return doc._id;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  })
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.startup(function(){
        // code to run on server at startup
    if (! Documents.findOne()) { // No docs yet.
      Documents.insert({title: "My new documents."})
    }
    })
}
```

---

I do not yet know what id="editor" does. I changed it to id="Editor" here, and even deleted it, with no perceived difference in the results between two windows.